# javascript regex multiline selector bbcode

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, multiline, bbcode

I'm using the newest version of the chrome browser on a mac book air with the newest OS. I'm trying to create a BBcode parser in javascript. I can easily parse one line code such as [b]a[/b] but when it's multiple lines, it doesn't find it. I did some research and found out javascript has some problems with the multiline (m) tag. I tried some alternative solutions and none of them seem to work. Here are some of my attempts:

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\[b\](.+)\\[\/b\]','igm');
var reg = new RegExp('\\[b\]([\s\S]+)\\[\/b\]','ig');
var reg = new RegExp('\\[b\]([^]+)\\[\/b\]','ig');
var reg = new RegExp('\\[b\]([\n|\r|.]+)\\[\/b\]','ig');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zw6wF/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must work:

```
 var reg = new RegExp('\\[b\\]([\\s\\S]+?)\\[/b\\]', 'ig');
```

or better:

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\[b]([\\s\\S]+?)\\[/b]', 'ig');
```

since you don't have to escape closing square brackets

Comment: I think the problem is that the + is too greedy.. his jfiddle sample shows multiple b tags in a single line. Otherwise I agree this should work

Comment: @Denomales: no the problem is that you must double escape all as in java with this syntax! But you are right a lazy quantifier is better.

Comment: @Denomales is right. I tried it and if there are multiple tags it only selects the first opening one and the last closing one ignoring everything in between

Comment: Yeah that works better for lines with multiple tags. And I didn't even notice the double escaped slashes +1

Comment: Or even `/\[b]([\s\S]+?)\[\/b]/ig`. I'd recommend `/\[b]([^]+?)\[\/b]/ig` but that doesn't work in some older IE versions.